# Python -How to solve OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, file, invalid-argument

I am learning about file objects in python but whenever i try to open file it shows the following error.

I have already checked that file is in same directory and it exists
this error occurs only if i name my file as test if i use any other name then it works fine
here's my CODE

```
f = open('C:\\Users\Tanishq\Desktop\python tutorials\test.txt', 'r')
```

here's the ERROR

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Tanishq/Desktop/question.py", line 1, in <module>
  f = open('C:\\Users\Tanishq\Desktop\python tutorials\test.txt', 'r')
  OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\Tanishq\\Desktop\\python   
  tutorials\test.txt'
```

Comment: You need to escape all of the `\ `s in your string or use a [raw string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) (that is, `r'...'`)

Comment: Place an `r` before the string and remove the double backslash.

Comment: You have to either escape all backslashes (`'C:\\\\Users\\Tanishq\\Desktop\\python tutorials\\test.txt'`) or use the raw string literal (`r'C:\\Users\Tanishq\Desktop\python tutorials\test.txt'`).

Comment: Thanks...it helped

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your issue is with backslashing characters like `\T` :

Try:

```py
f = open(r'C:\\Users\Tanishq\Desktop\python tutorials\test.txt', 'r')
```

Python uses `\` to denote special characters. Therefore, the string you provided does not actually truly represent the correct filepath, since Python will interpret `\Tanishq\` differently than the raw string itself. This is we we place the `r` in front of it. This lets Python know that we do indeed want to use the raw string and to treat `\` as a normal character.