# ‘OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument’ when attempting to open a file in the %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps directory

Tags: python, windows

Python won't let me open this file. Why not? The format of the command is correct, and it's definitely a file that exists on disk.

```
Python 3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os, os.path
>>> path = os.path.join(os.getenv('LOCALAPPDATA'), r"Microsoft\WindowsApps\ilspy.exe")
>>> f = open(path, "rb")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\<my name>\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\ilspy.exe'
>>>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python -How to solve OSError: \[Errno 22\] Invalid argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63194917/python-how-to-solve-oserror-errno-22-invalid-argument)

Comment: What have you found searching on the actual error message?

Comment: WindowsApps is protected by the system. Generally, users cannot access it. It is not that python does not allow you to open it.

Comment: @9769953, respectively: 1) there is nothing wrong with the format of the path. A path formatted in the same way successfully opens a file in another directory; 2) no it doesn't; 3) a load of other rubbish like the question you linked.

Comment: @Mechanic Pig, how may I evade this protection? This computer is my servant, not the other way around. I will not be told what I may and may not do on this computer, I won't have it.

Comment: Regardless of whether the computer is your servant or not, I think you can modify the problem properly so that people who know how to evade this protection will notice the problem.

Comment: @MechanicPig, what do you suggest?

Comment: I haven't tried to bypass this protection. You can search for relevant information. I tried to find some, like [How to Access the Protected WindowsApps Folder on Windows](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-access-windowsapps-folder/), which may be helpful to you.

Comment: But here, the WindowsApp folder is located inside a Users folder. Shouldn't it normally be located inside the Program Files folder? Wouldn't it having it in the current folder  automatically make it user readable?

Comment: @Hammerite no, your computer is not your servant. It's a device, and devices have to be safe. You can't format C: since the 2000s, or write to `Program Files`, precisely to prevent damaging the device and the applications on it. That's why `APPDATA` and `LOCALAPPDATA` exist. This prevented stupid developers from overwriting all your documents or desktop by deleting whatever the current folder was to "uninstall" it. Those developers tried to bypass this with elevated privileges which is why writes to protected folders are redirected now.

Comment: @Hammerite I'm not exaggerating either. I once had to help a friend that lost his entire PhD dissertation because a program "installed" itself on the desktop and just ... deleted the desktop when uninstalled.

Comment: @Hammerite in fact *you* don't want any old application reading your personal data stored by *another* application. You really don't want `CallOfDutyKeyGenerator` to read your tax returns for example, or the passwords stored locally in your password manager

Comment: But I do want Python to read this file - I'm telling the computer what to do here, not running malware or trashing the computer by mistake. Or if I am trashing it by mistake, it's my mistake to make. How do I let Python read this file?